# How to add a contour to light for an NPR shader?

Tags: lighting, grease-pencil, toon-shading, npr

I'm using Grease Pencils Lineart Modifier to outline objects. Freestyle works just as well.

How can I get the highlights to be contoured with the same stroke?

[image]

Here's the material.

[image]

Grease pencils Line Art modifier has an option "Light Contour" under Edge Types, but it doesn't work. The lights don't contour the round white dots or the rim lights.